# foreach loop in php to construct javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I am going to construct a popup javascript in php like this:

```
$popup_title = array(); 
$popup_text = array(); 
$popup_time = array();
$popup_delay = array(); 

array_push($popup_title, T_gettext("Ready for ..."));
array_push($popup_text, "<a href=\"x.php\">".T_gettext("Click here to...")."</a>"); 
array_push($popup_time, 3000);  
array_push($popup_delay, 6000);
```

here I make the javascript code:

```
if(!empty($popup_title)){
//constuct javascript

$popups = array();
foreach ( $popup_title as $key => $title )
{
    $popups[$key] = new stdClass();
    $popups[$key]->title = $title;
}
foreach ( $popup_text as $key => $text )
{
    $popups[$key]->text = $text;
}
foreach ( $popup_time as $key => $time )
{
    $popups[$key]->time = $time; 
}
//print javascript
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function(){"; 
foreach ( $popups as $popup ):
echo "
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.gritter.add("; echo json_encode($popup); echo ");
    }, ".($popup_delay");"; // <---------Here I need to place popup_delay 
    endforeach;
echo "  
});
</script>";
```

This gives this javascript for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.gritter.add({"title":"Ready for..","text":"<a href=\"x.php\">Click here to...<\/a>","time":3000});
    }, 0);  
});
</script>
```

I am not used to foreach. a for loop would be something like this:
 `for($n=0; $n < count($popup_delay); $n++){ echo $popup_delay[$n]; }`
, but how do I loop through the `$popup_delay` values with foreach, when I already use `json_encode($popup)` from `foreach ( $popups as $popup ):`

Comment: JSON Decode it back to a PHP array? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: You can nest `foreach` statements

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a single key for your array. So instead of creating multiple arrays in PHP, you can create a single multidimensional one like so:

```
$javascript_array = array();
$javascript_array[0]['title'] = "Ready for ...";
$javascript_array[0]['text'] = "Click here to...";
$javascript_array[0]['time'] = 3000;
$javascript_array[0]['delay'] = 6000;
```

Your array would be shown as such:

```
if ( !empty ( $javascript_array ) ) {
// dump in your <script> piece here
    foreach ( $javascript_array as $js_entry ) {
// put in your filler pieces here
        echo "Title: ".$js_entry['title'];
        echo "Text: ".$js_entry['text'];
        echo "Time: ".$js_entry['time'];
        echo "Delay: ".$js_entry['delay']; 
   } // end foreach
// closed </script> 
}
```